# Where to place SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java files in project?

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm very new to Android studio and I'm currently following a tutorial that implements a sliding tab layout for an application. The tutorial says to put
SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java in our project, but doesn't say exactly where. For now, I just put declared them as two classes and put them under the java folder. (...app\src\androidTest\java). However, when I try to include a SlidingTabLayout object in my xml file, it says "The following classes could not be: found:com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout", which means I must have put those two files in the wrong place. Anybody used these files before and know where to put them?

Thank you

Comment: place two classes into app\src\main\java in your_package. change classname name in xml like your_pacakge.SlidingTabLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says **could not found the SlidingTabLayout** class. Which means you have to tell correctly where the `SlidingTabLayout` file placed.

in xml change `com.android4devs.slidingtab` to your package name. You can find your package name in `SlidingTabLayout.java` or in `manifest` file.